# Using the "%" operator in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, operator-keyword

```
int i = 100;

do
{
    if (i % 5 = 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

When I try to compile the above code in my program I get the error:

```
"error: unexpected type
required: variable
found: value"
```

The caret key is under the % operator itself. I'm trying to write a program that will test all numbers from 100 to 200 to see if they're divisible by 5 or 6, and I'm already stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: need `==` not `=`!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `==` operator to compare the result of `i % 5` and `0`.  The `=` operator is the assignment operator.  The error message comes from the fact that you can't assign `0` to `i % 5`, which is not a variable.